# Prism Template pack: Xamarin forms - Fody exception

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I created a xamarin forms solution from Prism Template pack on visual studio on mac. I am getting Fody exception.

> Error: Fody: Could not inject EventInvoker method on type 'sdfdf.App'.
>   It is possible you are inheriting from a base class and have not
>   correctly set 'EventInvokerNames' or you are using a explicit
>   PropertyChanged event and the event field is not visible to this
>   instance. Either correct 'EventInvokerNames' or implement your own
>   EventInvoker on this class. If you want to suppress this place a
>   [DoNotNotifyAttribute] on sdfdf.App. (sdfdf)

I cannot compile any project because of fody weaver.
**FodyWeaver**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Weavers>
    <PropertyChanged EventInvokerNames="RaisePropertyChanged" />
    <RealmWeaver />
</Weavers>
```

If i remove `PropertyChanged` event from fody weaver, app is working fine but i need it for the app. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue ?

**UPDATE**

As per the suggestion, I updated the body weaver and got the following error.
**FodyWeaver**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Weavers>
    <PropertyChanged/>
    <RealmWeaver />
</Weavers>
```

> ```
> Error: Fody: An unhandled exception occurred: Exception: Could not resolve type with token 01000041 (from typeref, class/assembly
> ```
>
> Fody.TypeSystem, FodyHelpers, Version=3.1.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=1ca091877d12ca03) Type: System.TypeLoadException
>   StackTrace:   at ModuleWeaver.InitEventArgsCache () [0x00000] in
>   C:\projects\propertychanged\PropertyChanged.Fody\EventArgsCacheInjector.cs:5
>   at ModuleWeaver.Execute () [0x00084] in
>   C:\projects\propertychanged\PropertyChanged.Fody\ModuleWeaver.cs:29
>   at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   System.Object.lambda_method(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,object)
>   at InnerWeaver.ExecuteWeavers () [0x00087] in
>   C:\projects\fody\FodyIsolated\InnerWeaver.cs:200    at
>   InnerWeaver.Execute () [0x0004d] in
>   C:\projects\fody\FodyIsolated\InnerWeaver.cs:102  Source:
>   PropertyChanged.Fody TargetSite: Void InitEventArgsCache()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Fodyweavers you only need to add this:

```
<Weavers>
<PropertyChanged/>
</Weavers>
```

Documentation:

https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged

Comment: I updated my question, as per your reply i updated the body weaver and got a different error again.

Comment: I shared the error in the question. Its too big to share in the comment section.

Comment: Buddy remove <RealmWeaver /> tag from your fine. What is it for there?

Comment: It is needed for Realm Database used in the mobile app.

Comment: Do you need Fody to be pasting that piece of code for you? Anyway, clean and build and also check if your Xamarin.Forms version is the same across all your projects.

Comment: I did clean, no use, I commented out `<PropertyChanged/>` and its working fine. There is some issue with property change weaver. I need it as prism mvvm framework uses it for the binding.

Comment: Is your file xml file called FodyWeavers.xml ? Is it located in your PCL project?

Comment: It is in .net standard 2.0 library as well as iOS and Android projects. It compiles fine in my .net standard lib but it doesn't complier in iOS and android projects.

Comment: You don't need it in iOS and Android projects. You only RaisePropertyChange in your PCL project, where your pages are. Also make sure that nuget package downloaded is Fody.PropertyChanged not just Fody.

Comment: That's true, they were added during the project creation using prism template pack, let me remove it from the iOS and Android projects and try.

Comment: No worries. I would appreciate it if u select my answer as correct :)

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I did now.